# parent child relationships in controllers spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, inheritance, controller

I want to create multiple controllers in my project, the Url should start with one specific prefix and after that request should go through with a controller which is requested.

Urls Like:-

1. /api/parent
2. /api/parent/child-one
3. /api/parent/child-two
4. /api/parent/child-three
5. /api/parent/child-four

Here I want my controller's hierarchy like if I hit the first URL parent controller should call and if I hit the second URL the child-one controller should call.

**what is the best way to create this hierarchy?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use controller class like shown in below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "${spring.data.rest.base-path}/parent")
public class Parent {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Map> parentNode(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String,String> parth=new HashMap<>();
        parth.put("child-one", request.getRequestURL()+"/child-one");
        parth.put("child-two", request.getRequestURL()+"/child-two");
        parth.put("child-three", request.getRequestURL()+"/child-three");
        parth.put("child-four", request.getRequestURL()+"/child-four");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(parth);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/child-one" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> childOne() {

        return ResponseEntity.ok("child-one");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/child-two" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> childTwo() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("child-two");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/child-three" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> childThree() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("child-three");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/child-four" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> childFour() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("child-four");
    }
}
```

Spring-boot application.yml shown in below

```
server:
  port: 8089
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api/
```

result like below

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply what if I have the url like:-
1. /api/parent/child-one/subchild1
2. /api/parent/child-one/subchild2
3. /api/parent/child-two/subchild1
4. /api/parent/child-two/subchild2

then how can I design my classes.

Comment: use separate class for each child. ex: parent/child-one and method annotate with sub child1-2. Then if there is 5 child you have 5 classes and it contain sub child method